# Accessing a MySql (8.0.31) database with .NET 7 EF Core (in Visual Studio for Mac)

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-mac, .net-7.0

It's been days of researching and trying out many methods now. There seems to be no cohesive way out there to connect to a MySql Database in .NET 7 EF Core. MySQL workbench is used for the creation & hosting of the database. There is always some part that doesn't work, no matter which solution, explanation / tutorial I pick.

I'm trying to create a Contact Manager Web Application in C# with Visual Studio for MacOS.

Currently, the following code is my `Program.cs`:

```
using System.Xml;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace CMProject;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        // Add services to the container.
        var serverVersion = new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 31));
        string connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        builder.Services.AddDbContext<ContactManagerContext>(options => options.UseMySql(connectionString, serverVersion));

        builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

        var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.MapRazorPages();

        app.Run();
    }
}
```

And this is my ContactManagerContext:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace CMProject
{
    public class ContactManagerContext : DbContext
    {

        public ContactManagerContext(DbContextOptions<ContactManagerContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In some tutorial they access the data by creating new instances of the ContactManagerContext class in the main method as; `ContactContextManager context = new ContactContextManager()` and for the tutor in the video it works but on my end it says

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter 'options' of....

and so forth.

This is just one example of many, many issues.

I have tried so many different ways, I don't know what I seem to be doing wrong or missing.

Any ideas and advice are hugely appreciated.

Cheers,
J.

Comment: "There seems to be no cohesive way out there to connect to a MySql Database in .NET 7 EF Core." That's simply not true. Thousands of developers are successfully using https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/ to do so. Your question is very light on actual problem details (other than "I can't get it to work"). If you're encountering an exception, please include the _full_ exception message and complete call stack. https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Comment: True, I should've re-phrased it to "I've spent hours researching and the many solutions I've come across haven't worked so far." The solutions can quickly become outdated but anyways, I've come across a good tutorial that is working now thanks to the recent VS for Mac update which now implements a package console manager! Thanks for your input, Bradley.